# 'maximum call stack size exceed' when using Antd Menu inside HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, next.js

> 'maximum call stack size exceed'
>
> The above error occurred in the  component:
>       in Dashboard (created by withRedux(Dashboard))
>       in withRedux(Dashboard)

Whenever i use Antd Menu inside HOC wrapped component then suddenly i am getting this issue and Api request is called continuously. 
Even if i removed api request then also pages get crashed.

I used componentDidCatch to handle the error but i want to know what's the issue behind this Menu component of Antd.

I found this [A List of `antd`'s components that cannot work with HOC #4853](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/4853)

But others component don't give any problem just when i use Menu it's giving a problem.

Please give any suggestions regarding this.

I am using Next js, redux thunk with antd.

Answer (score 0):

```
'maximum call stack size exceed'
```

The above error occurred in the component: in Dashboard (created by withRedux(Dashboard)) in withRedux(Dashboard)

If you are getting this error it means `setState`  is called infinite time. You need to debug where its happeninng

Comment: if that's the case then why in other component use it's not giving a problem only in Menu it's giving a problem!?? And even there are no any setstate are called.

Comment: The issue i found is i changed all the nextconfig and babel file and It works fine... But now when i added require('dotenv').config() in next.config.js again the same issue arrived.

Comment: try to look at stack trace in console